# Good resource for chemical equivalence

Tags: physical-chemistry, reference-request

I need a good resource that explains the concept of chemical equivalence and its various application in physical chemistry. I have not found anything worthwhile from a Google search.

Comment: i have two sources, but it might not be that they're available on your continent?

Comment: @ADG: Mention them nonetheless. They might be available online.

Comment: Anyways they are Indian books: [RC Mukherjee](http://www.flipkart.com/author/r-c-mukherjee) and P Bahadur(Better get an old version of subjective one, which has many solved and unsolved examples)